# How to smooth a line ( point array ) in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose you have an array of Points that draw a line like this

[image]

yet it is a bit jagged and you want o make it smoother. what would you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: The technique in computer grahics is called antialiasing. Can you show us your code?

Comment: No, no, antialiasing. I need to get the points in the array moved so, that they would form a smooth line. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drawing points, draw a curve with those points using [`Graphics.DrawCurve(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te88b4a5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Works almost great, if I take every, say, 15th point and draw a curve between them. Only there should be a way for me to find and keep point in sharp corners, so that they won't get smoothed out. )

Comment: I added another answer addressing that. You can average the array before drawing the curve.

Answer (score 3):

You could average the points you have: Iterate through all the points in groups of three and bring the middle point in each of the groups closer to the center point between the two points. It would need some experimenting on how much to bring the points closer, but you could average the array several times.